# Recovering line of code that caused kernel panic

Tags: r, linux, crash, gdb, panic

I'm running CentOS 8.1 and my machine has kernel panic'd.  I installed the [kernel-debuginfo](https://serverfault.com/a/1050548/457889) package and I am generally following the steps in [Section 7.11 : Analyzing a core dump](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_monitoring_and_updating_the_kernel/installing-and-configuring-kdump_managing-monitoring-and-updating-the-kernel#analyzing-a-core-dump_installing-and-configuring-kdump).

Here is an abbreviated version of my debugging session :

```
# crash /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64/vmlinux /var/crash/XXX/vmcore
.
.
. 
WARNING: kernel relocated [336MB]: patching 93296 gdb minimal_symbol values

      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/modules/4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/XXX/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 48
        DATE: Sun Jan 10 13:36:04 2021
      UPTIME: 23 days, 22:18:40
LOAD AVERAGE: 10.00, 10.01, 10.00
       TASKS: 1966
    NODENAME: YYY
     RELEASE: 4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Wed Dec 4 21:51:45 UTC 2019
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2794 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 2035.9 GB
       PANIC: "Kernel panic - not syncing: Hard LOCKUP"
         PID: 27666
     COMMAND: "R"
        TASK: ffff8ff017978000  [THREAD_INFO: ffff8ff017978000]
         CPU: 2
       STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)
crash> bt
PID: 27666  TASK: ffff8ff017978000  CPU: 2   COMMAND: "R"
 #0 [ffffb5187c6c7a50] machine_kexec at ffffffff96057c4e
 #1 [ffffb5187c6c7aa8] __crash_kexec at ffffffff96155b8d
 #2 [ffffb5187c6c7b70] panic at ffffffff960b0578
 #3 [ffffb5187c6c7bf8] watchdog_overflow_callback.cold.8 at ffffffff9618bb11
 #4 [ffffb5187c6c7c08] __perf_event_overflow at ffffffff961f54f2
 #5 [ffffb5187c6c7c38] x86_pmu_handle_irq at ffffffff96007a16
 #6 [ffffb5187c6c7e88] amd_pmu_handle_irq at ffffffff96008b14
 #7 [ffffb5187c6c7ea0] perf_event_nmi_handler at ffffffff960060cd
 #8 [ffffb5187c6c7eb8] nmi_handle at ffffffff96021843
 #9 [ffffb5187c6c7f10] default_do_nmi at ffffffff96021cce
#10 [ffffb5187c6c7f30] do_nmi at ffffffff96021ea8
#11 [ffffb5187c6c7f50] nmi at ffffffff96a01537
    RIP: 0000146816a69d6e  RSP: 00007ffc378f6270  RFLAGS: 00000216
    RAX: 000000006655e8df  RBX: 0000000000000003  RCX: 000000000003ad90
    RDX: 0000000000000003  RSI: 0000000007ccb060  RDI: 000000076fe90140
    RBP: 0000000000085fc6   R8: 0000000000b13039   R9: 00000007770c0758
    R10: 0000000778ba8a38  R11: 0000000000000c36  R12: 000000000070e070
    R13: 0000000000000000  R14: 00007ffc378f6410  R15: 00007ffc378f6430
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

Clearly the culprit is an `R` process which I was running (see `COMMAND: "R"`).  Looking at the `bt` above, it seems like it is only returning the kernel level functions.  I want to know what line in my `R` code (or installed `R` libraries) causing the issue.   Trying

```
crash> gdb bt
No stack.
gdb: gdb request failed: bt
crash>
```

is not useful.  Looking at `man crash` it isn't directly obvious how to do that.  Some of the R libraries possibly involved have C++ code that was compiled with debug flags.  I have a vague hope of the cause of the error being in one of these.

QUESTION :

1. How do I use the Linux `crash` utility to recover the line of code (either R or C++) that caused the kernel to panic?
2. What is a "Kernel panic - not syncing: Hard LOCKUP"